# Xslt change element name

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to change a xml element with xslt.

XML:

```
 <PARAM name="ulang" value="de" original_value="de"/>
 <PARAM name="wc" value="200" original_value="200"/>
 <PARAM name="wc_mc" value="1" original_value="1"/>
 <RES SN="1" EN="727">
   <M>727</M>
   <XT/>
   <R N="1" L="1" MIME="text/plain">
     <U>url</U>
     <UE>url</UE>
     <UD>url</UD>
     <RK>10</RK>
     <MT N="Content_Length" V="42"/>
     <MT N="url_id" V="005056A51FAC1EE0B9A3EF696BB229CB"/>
```

I tried to change it with this xslt:

```
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="MT[@N='url_id']">
    <xsl:attribute name="url-id">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

I want that url_id change to url-id.

The result should be looking like this:

```
 <PARAM name="ulang" value="de" original_value="de"/>
 <PARAM name="ulang" value="de" original_value="de"/>
 <PARAM name="wc" value="200" original_value="200"/>
 <PARAM name="wc_mc" value="1" original_value="1"/>
 <RES SN="1" EN="727">
   <M>727</M>
   <XT/>
   <R N="1" L="1" MIME="text/plain">
     <U>url</U>
     <UE>url</UE>
     <UD>url</UD>
     <RK>10</RK>
     <MT N="Content_Length" V="42"/>
    <MT N="url-id" V="005056A51FAC1EE0B9A3EF696BB229CB"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your question mentions changing an element name, but it looks like you actually want to change an attribute? Do you want to change the value of the attribute, or the name of attribute? It would probably help if you showed the XML you expect to be output. Thanks!

Comment: I added the result that i expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template is matching the `MT` element, and trying to create an attribute in place of that element.

You need to change your template to the match the attribute instead...

```
<xsl:template match="MT/@N[. = 'url_id']">
  <xsl:attribute name="N">
    <xsl:value-of select="'url-id'"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Or even this...

```
<xsl:template match="MT/@N[. = 'url_id']">
  <xsl:attribute name="N">url-id</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```